# MVVMCross ListView - how to populate only with the list items matches certain conditions?

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross

MVVMCross ListView  - How to display a list of items in a listview grouped by a status? For exampled activate or deactivated

I have added two listview to the layout and set the datasource to have two lists (activatedItems and deactivatedItems => both of them derived from ListOfItems. ) using the xaml data binding with now code behind. But had a problem in the data not updated when there is a change to the underlying list (ListOfItems).

To resolve this, I have to re create the UI by setting the content view whenever there a change to the data set.

This is not an elegant solution and I would like to have one listview with sections "Activated" and "Deactivated". Then on touching the Activated item should get added to the Deactivated list and the UI should reflect the same.

Comment: Can you share how are you binding this list? A sample code would be appreciated in order to properly help you.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/jeevaeastpoint/9e344ecc3e6a7b76a343cf994d274435

Comment: @JordiVilaplana Added the example layouts used. in the gist file.

Comment: It seems there's nothing wrong with the layouts, maybe there is with the view model. Could you show us the `ActiveLoginItems` and `DeactivatedLoginItems` properties from your view model and the object model from the list? Maybe we can make a work-around with the `get`ters.

Comment: The current code actually works with two list view and required to setcontent view when there is change in the data set.  But I wanted to use one listview rather than having two.  Is there a way to use one listview with sections. There are two sections (activate and deactivated).

Comment: That was a work around i found.

Comment: here is the link for current viewmodel https://gist.github.com/jeevaeastpoint/996bd7f25362b824f9c68ed249f15cbc

Comment: So are you trying to sort that list by `Activated`/`Deactivated` item status and not filtering them?

Comment: Yes, The list will have two sections "Activated" and "Deactivated" group by isActivated flag.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149941/discussion-between-jordivilaplana-and-jeeva).

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a `LoginItemModel` with a `Title` property (let's assume it's a `string` property), I would recommend you to extract this to an `ILoginItemModel` interface and also add a `bool IsHeader` property. This way:

```
public interface ILoginItemModel {
    public bool IsHeader { get; }
    public LoginSection ItemGroup { get; }
    public string Title { get; }
}
```

Make your `LoginItemModel` extend this `ILoginItemModel` interface and make `IsHeader` always return `false`.

```
public bool IsHeader => false;
```

Write a second class extending this same interface, let's call it `LoginItemHeaderModel`. This class will just have these three properties:

```
public class LoginItemHeaderModel : ILoginItemModel {
    public bool IsHeader => true;

    LoginSection _itemGroup;
    public LoginSection ItemGroup => _itemGroup;

    string _title;
    public string Title => _title;

    public LoginItemHeaderModel(LoginSection itemGroup, string title) {
        _itemGroup = itemGroup;
        _title = title;
    }
}
```

Now we have two models that fits into a single `IList<ILoginItemModel>`.

Back to your view model, you can declare a fourth list property and put it all together along with your new headers:

```
public List<ILoginItemModel> SectionedLoginItems {
    get {
        var values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(LoginSection)).Cast<LoginSection>();
        List<ILoginItemModel> list = new List<ILoginItemModel>();

        foreach (LoginSection loginSection : values) {
            list.Add(new LoginItemHeaderModel(loginSection, loginSection.ToString()));
            list.AddRange(LoginItems.Where(l => l.ItemGroup == loginSection));
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

Now you have your single sorted and with section headers list.

You should now write a new layout for those header items (aren't you going to make them look like the common items, right?) and, in your custom `MvxAdapter`, inside the `GetBindableView` method, check whether the `object source` (which will be an `ILoginItemModel` object) is a header item or not.

Comment: Hi @JordiVilaplana, It works fine but the list view is not refreshed. The items activated still stays in the Deactivated group. On touching an item from the list, i take the user to a screen where user will enter the email address and click either cancel or done. On clicking one of these buttons will take back to the previous section. The list doesn't refresh as it is modified behind the scene. not sure what is happening.

Comment: I have to explicity call SetContentView(Resource.Layout.LoginsProfileItemView);  and invalidate the listview then set the adapter. Only then the listview is refreshed. I thought the MVVMCross plugin takes care of this.

Comment: @Jeeva I think this qualifies for a different new question. Made my answer based on your original (unedited) question after the clarifications: **how to display your list with sections**. Please, let's solve one problem at a time. Your comments bring up new questions (how are your items stored? how is your list displayed/refreshed? how do you navigate between screens?) that may be better answered in a new post. Of course, feel free to accept my answer if it fits for your first answer.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you make a change to ActiveLoginItems or DeactivatedLoginItems, make a call to RaisePropertyChanged in your ViewModel i.e.

```
RaisePropertyChanged(() => ActiveLoginItems);
```

or

```
RaisePropertyChanged(() => DeactivatedLoginItems);
```

That should make the MvxListView update with the changes.